# How do I get the count of rows using Bookshelf?

Tags: node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

How can I get the number of rows (without any filter)?

I've tried this `User.fetch().count()` and `User.count()`, but I get these errors respectively:

```
TypeError: User.fetch is not a function

AssertionError: expected { Object (_bitField, _fulfillmentHandler0, ...) } to equal 0
```

Here's my model:

```
let bookshelf = require('../config/database');

require('./role');

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    role: function() {
        return this.hasOne(Role);
    }
});

module.exports = bookshelf.model('User', User);
```

Comment: Oh, and by the way: use this.hasOne(require("./role")) instead of early require. i figured out that sometimes it can lead you into circular dependencies issues, :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const knex = require("knex")(require("./knexfile").development);
const Bookshelf = require("bookshelf")(knex);

const User = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: "user",
  idAttribute: "userid"
});

knex.migrate.latest().then(_ => {

  User.forge().count().then(ret => {
    console.log(ret);
    process.exit(0);
  });

});
```

the output should be:

```
[sombriks@sephiroth sample-knex-bookshelf]$ node index.js
Knex:warning - sqlite does not support inserting default values. Set the `useNullAsDefault` flag to hide this warning. (see docs http://knexjs
.org/#Builder-insert).
3
[sombriks@sephiroth sample-knex-bookshelf]$
```

please take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/sombriks/sample-knex-bookshelf) if you want a more detailed info.